# Primefaces ajax update not working for field inside <p:column>

Tags: java, html, primefaces

I have a primefaces code like this.
After selecting the drop down, if the value is 'M', I want to render a comment textarea.

It works fine and shows the textarea, but on selecting 'F', it is not hiding the textarea even though the renderComments value is false.

I think the update is not happening properly because of the < p: column> tag.
How to fix this, please

**HTML**

```
        <p:panelGrid>

            <p:row>
                <p:column style="width:15%">
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="gender" value="#{myBean.model.gender}">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="M" itemLabel="Male" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="F" itemLabel="Female" />
                        <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{myBean.genderListener}" process="@this" update="commentsCol comments" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </p:column>

                <p:column id="commentsCol" style="width:50%">
                    <p:inputTextarea id="comments" cols="100" rows="2" value="#{myBean.model.comments}" rendered="#{myBean.renderComments}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:row>


        </p:panelGrid>
```

**Bean**

```
/**
 * Event for gender.
 */
public void genderListener() {

    if ("M".equalsIgnoreCase(model.getGender())) {
        renderComments = true;
    }
    else {
        renderComments = false;
    }
}
```

**Update**

If I use update="@form" it works. However it updates the whole form which I dont expect. Not sure what is wrong if I specify only the ids (commentsCol comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this by wrapping a < h: panelGroup> around the element and using the panelGroup id alone to update.

The equivalent full code is like this

```
    <p:panelGrid>
        <p:row>
            <p:column style="width:15%">
                <p:selectOneMenu id="gender" value="#{myBean.model.gender}">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="M" itemLabel="Male" />
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="F" itemLabel="Female" />
                    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{myBean.genderListener}" process="@this" update="commentsPanel" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </p:column>

            <p:column style="width:50%">
                <h:panelGroup id="commentsPanel">               
                    <p:inputTextarea id="comments" cols="100" rows="2" value="#{myBean.model.comments}" rendered="#{myBean.renderComments}" />
                </h:panelGroup>
            </p:column>
        </p:row>

    </p:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem by putting an id on the `p:panelGrid` and updating that instead of the column.

```
    <p:panelGrid id="foo">

        <p:row>
            <p:column style="width:15%">
                <p:selectOneMenu id="gender" value="#{myBean.model.gender}">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="M" itemLabel="Male" />
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="F" itemLabel="Female" />
                    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{myBean.genderListener}" process="@this" update="foo" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="commentsCol" style="width:50%">
                <p:inputTextarea id="comments" cols="100" rows="2" value="#{myBean.model.comments}" rendered="#{myBean.renderComments}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:row>


    </p:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo in my psedo code only. I corrected now. In actual code, it is all fine. In fact, the flag renderComments  returns true & false correctly as expected for the dropdown selection, but only the problem remains somewhere in updating the field.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts. That is better than update="@form" and works, but however, I have another set of fields inside this grid and updates those fields as well. Maybe I have to use another panelGrid for those fields. I don't understand why individual fields not working. Could be some more syntax missing.

Comment: @Jay I'm not sure. I saw that the ajax update was removing the `<td>` from the generated HTML when trying to update just the column which I thought was odd. I think wrapping the different sections in panel grids might be your best bet.

Comment: Sorry mate that was not the complete answer, that's a workaround.  I used < h: panelGroup> to fix that. But I appreciate the efforts. Thanks

Comment: Well the root problem was that you needed to update the container of <p:row> instead of the <p:column> but answer is chosen at your discretion so I understand.

Comment: Did you wrap the <p:column> in <h:panelGroup> ? If so, I see what you mean about it being a workaround

Comment: Please see the working code in my answer. If we wrap the <p: column> with <h: panelGroup> there would be alignment issues. So <h: panelGroup> should be inside the <p: column>

Comment: Ah ok, I see what you mean now

Answer (score 0):

Try to update "comments" instead of "commentsCol"

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work. I already tried that and other different combinations.